# Javascript debugging: stopping/breaking at every javascript invocation

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, breakpoints

I am dealing with a complex legacy javascript code base, and it's difficult to figure out where to put breakpoint (I have to find the files, put a breakpoint in firebug etc).

Is there a way so that Firebug breaks on the first javascript execution that it encounters every time?

In other words, every time I click on something on the page, and if a javascript code is executed, I want Firebug to break on that line?

Of course I don't want Firebug to stop when it executes it's internal javascript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The latest build has a [pause] button for it.

You can read more about it here : http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#suspend

Comment: There is even a blog post about it : http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-15-break-on-next/

Comment: This works. The bad thing is that we have an onMouseMove event that catches everything. Is there a way to ignore a specific function?